# Overriding the equals method - having trouble

Tags: java, overriding

guys and/or gals.  I'm having some trouble with this programming assignment for my Programming 2 class.  I feel a bit ashamed that I'm so lost since I seemed to excel in the prior class.  I apologize in advance for what is most likely a trivial problem, but I'm having trouble applying any solutions I find online to my specific code.  Long story short, I've got a Car constructor that has two strings for a make and model (i.e. Honda, civic, respectively).

```
public Car(String make, String model, double basePrice, String plateNum)
{
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.basePrice = basePrice;
    this.plateNum = plateNum;
}
```

In order for the equals method to function, the cars must have the same make and model.  Here's what I keep messing with, but it always returns false.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other)
{
    if(!(other instanceof Car))
        return false;

    Car temp = (Car)other;


    if(this.equals(temp.getMake()) && this.equals(temp.getModel()))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

I've tried it without the "not" in front of the instanceof if statement, and I've tried inverting the this and temp, to no avail.  I know giving out answers to homework is frowned upon, and I understand it completely.  If not, perhaps someone could be kind enough to explain what I'm doing wrong?  I'm not entirely sure what "this" means.  I imagine that it is essentially a placeholder for what will be calling the method.  In this case, it would be a *CarObject*.equals.

Anyway, thank you again in advance.  This website has helped me out many times in the past, I'm looking forward to any replies. :)

Comment: You are comparing `temp.getMake()` with `this` when you should compare it with `this.getMake()`. The same for the other one.

Comment: I've been working on this for a few days and only now, after I just posted this question, do I realize it should be calling the getMake and getModel methods in the if statement.  I feel so silly.  I hope someone sees this and hopefully they avoid the same mistake I have.  Apologizes for the useless question.